# Como puedo rellenar filas automáticamente con diferentes registros en php y javascript

Tags: php, javascript

tengo el siguiente problema y no se como puedo hacerlo:

Tengo un formulario que se llama index.php ese formulario al guardarse me re-direcciona al archivo trabajo.php

En trabajo.php llamo los datos insertados del formulario inicial index.php:

trabajo.php

```
<script>
// nuevo método para eliminar la fila, recibe como parámetro el botón presionado 
// y navega hasta el nodo de la fila para eliminarla

 function eliminarFilatre(boton){
 // navegar hasta el nodo fila
 fila = boton.parentNode.parentNode;
 // navegar al nodo superior de la fila y borrar la fila
 fila.parentNode.removeChild(fila);


}
    function guardar(){

        var _posatendi = document.getElementById("posatendi").value;
        var _tipotrabajo = document.getElementById("tipotrabajo").value;
        var _horainicio = document.getElementById("horainicio").value;

        var fila="<tr><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='posatendi[]' value='"+_posatendi+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='tipotrabajo[]' value='"+_tipotrabajo+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>" +
            "<input type='time' name='horainicio[]' value='"+_horainicio+"' readonly>"+
            "</td></tr>" +          

 // botón que llama al método eliminar fila y pasa como parámetro
 // el botón
"<td><button onclick='eliminarFilatre(this)'>-</button></td>" ;

        var btn = document.createElement("TR");
        btn.innerHTML=fila;
        document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
    }

</script>

<button onclick="guardar()">+</button>

<form action="guardar_trabajos.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" id="idtrabajo" name="idtrabajo" value="<?php echo $idtrabajo?>" readonly="readonly" />   

    <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablita">

            </tbody>
        </table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Iniciar trabajos"/>         
</form>
```

En ese formulario de trabajo.php uso javascript para ir seleccionando los trabajos y el los agrega en forma de filas en el  esto para luego guardar todo ese arreglo en mi base de datos, todo eso funciona perfecto.

Ahora como puedo hacer para decirle a ese id="tablita" que me cree las filas automáticamente de acuerdo a la cantidad de trabajos que ya vienen en el formulario anterior que es trabajo.php.

El ejemplo seria el siguiente: en el formulario principal (index.php) tengo un campo que dice 1,2 eso significa que son dos trabajos diferentes. trabajo 1 y trabajo 2.

Entonces que en el formulario de id="tablita" debería cargarme automáticamente 2 filas con esos nros 1 y 2. los trabajos pueden ser cualquier nro, puede decir 3,4 o 5,6 se separan por comas. mi idea seria esa, cargar automáticamente las filas dependiendo de la cantidad de trabajos y que rellene con los nros correspondientes.

Si el trabajo es 1,2 serian 2 filas la primera con el nro 1 y la segunda con el nro 2.

y ya lo demas esta hecho solo seria presionar guardar y ya se inserta todo en la base de datos.

Otra cosa en las filas de id='tablita' guardo 3 campos el único que debería llenarse solo seria posatendi[] los demás deben quedar vacíos los selecciona el usuario.

Cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no lo he entendido mal, lo que necesitas es separar en varios números una cadena que rellenas en el index.php y crear una fila para cada uno de estos números.

Lo puedes hacer de forma sencilla con php, haces un explode de este valor, y luego repites tantas lineas como números tengas. Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$valorTrabajos = '1, 2';
$trabajos = explode(',', $valorTrabajos);


foreach($trabajos as $trabajo) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" value="' . $trabajo . '"/></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: excelente eso era lo que necesitaba, muchísimas gracias. :)

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar `inputs` dinámicos debes agregar dentro del `while` el código html:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT id, trabajoNombre FROM Trabajos WHERE idPersona = ".$_GET['idPersona'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<input type = 'text' id='" . $row["id"]. "' value= '". $row["trabajoNombre"]. >";
    echo "<br>";
  }
} 


?>
```

Comment: buenos días, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.